# Let aggregate continue even if a $lookup fails

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I got a long aggregate and inside this aggregate is this $lookup:

```
{ '$lookup': { from: 'users', localField: 'user', foreignField: '_id', as: 'users' } },
{ '$unwind': '$users' },
```

The problem is that if it does not find the user in users, then it will skip the entire record and not return anything in $project.

Is there a way to do " $lookup, and if you fail just show the main record anyway" ?

Here is the full aggregate just in case:

```
db.booking.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': 
        { 
            status: { '$in': [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9 ] }, 
            '$or': [ 
                { checkin: { '$gte': 1516320000 }, checkout: { '$lte': 1521417600 } }, 
                { checkin: { '$lt': 1516320000 }, checkout: { '$gt': 1521417600 } }, 
                { checkin: { '$lt': 1516320000 }, checkout: { '$gt': 1516320000 } }, 
                { checkin: { '$lt': 1521417600 }, checkout: { '$gt': 1521417600 } } 
            ] 
        }
    }, 
    { '$sort': { checkin: 1 } }, 
    { '$lookup': { from: 'users', localField: 'user', foreignField: '_id', as: 'users' } }, { '$unwind': '$users' }, 
    { '$project': { _id: 1, property: 1, user: 1, name: '$users.name', country: '$users.country', checkin: 1, checkout: 1, priceNight: 1, status: 1, source: 1 } } 
], {})
```

Comment: Use [`preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#missing-field) option with `$unwind` to retain the row. Something like `{ '$unwind': {path:'$users',preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true }}`. You can rewrite the last part of aggregation to just use project after lookup without $unwind stage

Comment: Veeram!! you are still here :D  Was hoping you would answer this one hehe.  I got a comment in my code saying //Veeram said something about preserveNull...  so you probably helped me before.  Let me try this at once.

Comment: Confirmed...  `{ '$lookup': { from: 'users', localField: 'user', foreignField: '_id', as: 'users' } },  { '$unwind': {path:'$users',preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true }},` worked perfectly!!  Thanks again Veeram :)

Comment: @s7vr the world deserve more men like you. You saved my day!!